Google Sheets Apps Script unexpected setValue() behaviour with some Unicode characters
setValue() when asked to set the value of a cell to certain Unicode characters, refuses and instead decides to set the value to the last digit of the codepoint (as a numeric type)
Disclaimer: I am not very experienced with JS
I've been working on a Unicode spreadsheet to contain all characters and some associated data (correct to Unicode 15.1) - and have made a script to transfer raw data from an old sheet (correct to Unicode 12.1), however for some specific characters, the apps script consistently refuses to setValue() to what I ask and instead sets the value to be:

Of the numeric type
Equal to the last digit of the codepoint
The puzzling part about this is that it does this every time for the same characters, however I cannot find any pattern to what characters these are, except for that the codepoints always end in 0-9 (never A-F, even in the middle of a problematic range as soon as the codepoint ends with A-F it correctly sets the value). These problematic ranges are relatively rare and usually only 16 characters in size, but they seem randomly distributed throughout the entirety of Unicode characters which need two surrogate pairs (well, it might be happening far sooner but I havent observed it myself yet).

To demonstrate this behaviour, I have set up two simple spreadsheets. The first, called "s1" contains the following values in cells A1 to F10 (copied with Ctrl + Shift + V)
130032    TRUE        Recipe for these is in the Missing Characters sheet
130033    TRUE        
130034    TRUE    U+2b52  Unicode 10.0    
130035    TRUE      Next Letter 
130036    TRUE        
130037    TRUE      Next Letter 
130038    TRUE        
130039    TRUE      Next Letter 
130040    TRUE        
130041    TRUE        

This is some Unicode characters and some data associated with them, the specifics of which aren't currently important.
The second sheet, named "s2" contains the same values in columns A-C however columns D-F have been emptied in order to demonstrate the failure of setValue() to do what I expected, resulting in the following (again copied with Ctrl + Shift + V):
130032    TRUE            
130033    TRUE            
130034    TRUE            
130035    TRUE            
130036    TRUE            
130037    TRUE            
130038    TRUE            
130039    TRUE            
130040    TRUE            
130041    TRUE

Now, for the code I am running to demonstrate the behaviour, I simply transfer the data in s1 over to s2, with some additional layers of decomposition so that the inspection of values can be performed like it would be in the real sheet. The code is as follows:
function omg(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ranges_str = ["s1!A1:F10", "s2!A1:F10"];
  ranges_obj = [spreadsheet.getRange(ranges_str[0]), spreadsheet.getRange(ranges_str[1])];
  values = [ranges_obj[0].getValues(), ranges_obj[1].getValues()];
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    values_in = values[0][i];
    console.log(["Initial in", values_in]); // intended values, note the presence of unicode characters
    values_out = values[1][i];
    console.log(["Initial out", values_out]); // empty, as intended
    for (k = 3; k < 6; k++){
      console.log(["Setting Cell To", values_in[k]])
      ranges_obj[1].getCell(i + 1, k +1).setValue(values_in[k].toString()); // setting values
      console.log(["Cell Was Set To", ranges_obj[1].getCell(i + 1, k +1).getValue()]); // does not match sometimes
    }
  }
}

The output of this code is quite comedic. For example, the 4th and 3rd last outputs to console (corresponding to the last non-blank cell in the range in s1) are the following:
[ 'Setting Cell To', '' ]
[ 'Cell Was Set To', 8 ]

This behaviour persists even if I setValue('') (char U+1fbf8, example from the 9th row) directly, so clearly it really thinks that the number 8 is appropriate to assign here.
I find this quite amazing because I know that JavaScript uses UTF-16 and so there is sometimes some "unexpected" behaviour from operations such as .length, however this takes it to another level. To only do this for seemingly totally random characters is simply so hilarious and infuriating to me that I have no choice but to ask: What on earth is going on????
Edit: It is worth noting that this issue is native to the Sheets environment itself - even formulas such as SPLIT() within the spreadsheet make identical errors for identical characters, which makes me quite worried.
Edit 2: I believe I have found the pattern. It looks like all the problematic characters have a defined numeric value in the Unicode Database, and for some reason sheets thinks that I am asking to set to this value (I am not, if you were wondering). Must I really prepend an apostrophe to such characters? If so, can someone provide a sample way to perform this algorithmically (remember I am not particularly experienced in JS)?

The question is showing rectangle , so it's nuclear what are the problemática characters. I'

Welcome to stack overflow! Can you edit your post and share with us a sample date in the form of a sample Google Sheets so that we may try to replicate the issue you encountered on our side? As far as what I can see from your post, I can also see rectangles as what @Wicket has also seen.

The question doesn't show the "unicode characters" that it's talking about so, it's not possible to know what exactly is happening.
Please bear in mind that Google Sheets cells might contain rich text but built-in functions and SpreadsheetApp.Range methods getValue, getValues, getDisplayValue and getDisplayValues will parse the cell content as plain text. Fortunately Google Apps Script has Class RichTextValue and SpreadsheetApp.Range has the method getRichTextValue and getRichTextValues to get the rich text content from a cell.
Please spend some time learning about using rich text in Google Sheets as well about using Google Apps Script to handle it.
Related

Script to colour specific characters in a sheet

